# Index-based access to a C++ list

Tags: c++

For several reasons I need to use a C++ list (not a vector) but need to have index-based access to the elements.

I came up with something like this:

```
point* point1i = std::next(listPoints.begin(), i);
point* point2i = std::next(listPoints.begin(), i + 1);
```

where `point` is a class declared elsewhere and `i` is an integer.

But when I compile I get this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::_List_iterator<point*>’ to ‘point*’ in initialization
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need random access to elements of your container (access-by-index) then `std::list` is not the right tool for the job. It's doubtful your other reasons for using a list justify it's use.

Comment: Sharing @FrançoisAndrieux's doubts – maybe you want to share the reasons you need a `std::list`?

Comment: Note that `std::next` will run off the end of the list, with bad consequences, if `i` is too large.

Comment: Depending on your reasons, you might also consider [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Comment: Instructor made us use a list. Should've clarified that. Really don't agree but what can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`listPoints.begin()` and `std::next` deal with iterators. Since you seem to have a `std::list<point *>` and need the element, just dereference said iterators:

```
point* point1i = *std::next(listPoints.begin(), i);
point* point2i = *std::next(listPoints.begin(), i + 1);
```

Comment: Note also that if you really need 2 nodes, where the 2nd node is just +1 (or any relative offset) from the 1st node, you should save the iterator from the 1st call to `std::next()` and pass it to the 2nd call to `std::next()` so you don't re-iterate the entire list from the beginning again: `auto iter = std::next(listPoints.begin(), i); point* point1i = *iter; point* point2i = *std::next(iter/*, 1*/);`